# Wordpress site has 6000 posts, causing it to be slow

Tags: database, wordpress

These posts are being treated as listings for a directory, but they are not loading all at the same time.

I think it may be a database issue, I noticed my wp_postmeta size is over 20Mb

I ruled out all js and css issues already.

Thanks!

Comment: 6000 posts are nothing for a db.Look into slow query log,not much info in your question for an answer.

Comment: Are you on a shared or dedicated host? 6,000 isn't a lot but on a shared host with a million other people with 6,000 posts it might be

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to help you track the slow database queries…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a plug-in is causing your site to slow down. You could check this just to be sure... You can always check your database or something like that but sometimes it could be much smaller than you'd think. Also,

Use a plug-in like wp super cache to generate html files which makes your site slightly faster. Caching is always good in my opinion.

That said, run a db check.